# Unable to remove all object from vector

Tags: c++, object, vector

so basically i have a vector of objects called "Things" that I populate over the console. These are the name of the object I populate them with (tom, coin, coin, bomb).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  for (Thing * t : *locations[i]->getThings()) {
     if (t->getName().compare("bomb") == 0){
        for (Thing * all : *locations[i]->getThings()){
            if(all->getName().compare("tom") != 0){
                 locations[i]->remove(all);
             }
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

This code is run every time to check if there is a "thing" object called bomb in the list and would remove every other object other than tom.

So from the populated example above, the expected list should just be {tom}. However when the code runs it is {tom, coin} which means it fails to delete the other "non-tom" object

Comment: Removing an item from a container while iterating the container is fraught with peril. Consider using [the Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) instead.

Comment: Your iterator (and please, consider calling it something like `it` rather than `all`) may become invalid when you remove the object it points at from the container.

Comment: @TimRandall `all` is not an iterator

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are modify the `Things` vector while you are still iterating through it, so you are going to be invalidating the iterators that the `for` loops are using, which is *undefined behavior*.

You can do something more like this instead, using the [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```cpp
const auto is_bomb = [](const Thing *t){ return t->getName() == "bomb"; };
const auto is_not_tom = [](const Thing *t){ return t->getName() != "tom"; };
...
auto *things = locations[i]->getThings();
if (std::any_of(things->begin(), things->end(), is_bomb)){
    things.erase(
        std::remove_if(things->begin(), things->end(), is_not_tom),
        things->end()
    );
}
```

Or, if you are using C++20 or later:

```cpp
const auto is_bomb = [](const Thing *t){ return t->getName() == "bomb"; };
const auto is_not_tom = [](const Thing *t){ return t->getName() != "tom"; };
...
auto *things = locations[i]->getThings();
if (std::any_of(things->begin(), things->end(), is_bomb)){
    std::erase_if(*things, is_not_tom);
}
```